# Granting access to google drive after signing up the user

Tags: google-drive-api

I recently visited a website which gave me a google drive link to access the content but when I tried to open the link it said permission denied. So I signed up at that website and now the drive link opened fine.

So what I observed is the website shared the drive content with users who had signed up.

So I am curious How do you implement this ? i.e How do you provide read access to
only those users that signed up at your website?

Answer (score 0):

When you are the owner of a shared drive, you can easily manage the members of it - either adding and/or removing them and changing the permissions for each of them.

This can be done using the UI of Google Drive:

[image: shared drive]

But it can also be done programmatically as well by making use of the Drive API and of the following request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions
```

#### Code snippet

```
var newMember = {
  type: 'user',
  role: 'reader',
  emailAddress: 'user@example.com'
};

driveService.permissions.create({
         resource: newOrganizerPermission,
         fileId: 'driveId',
         useDomainAdminAccess: true,
         supportsAllDrives: true,
         fields: 'id'
         }, callback);
```

So for example, whenever a new member is being registered, a script with the instructions above is run and the email address is added to the viewers of the shared drive.

#### Reference

- [Drive API Permissions:create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create);
- [Manage shared drive users and activity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337635?hl=en&ref_topic=7337266).